# Elastic search with django parler

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

So i am trying to add Parler to my django application and it can't find a field that i want to index

`models.py`

```
class Document(models.Model):

    class DocumentStatus(models.TextChoices):
        ACTIVE = 'active', 'Active'
        ARCHIVED = 'archived', 'Archived'

    translations = TranslatedFields(
     header = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
     body = RichTextField()
)
   
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = DocumentStatus.choices, default = DocumentStatus.ACTIVE)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name = "document_language", on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.header
```

`documents.py` for elastic search:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from . import models

@registry.register_document
class DocDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        name = 'documents'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards':1,
            'number_of_replicas':0
        }
    class Django:
        model = models.Document
        fields = [
            'header'
        ]
```

the error it throws:

> Document has no field "header"

I tried to do it with other fields that are not in `translations` but it throws the same error:

> Document has no field "whatever_field_i_have_used"